# How to send a .txt file in blob as an attachment in an email in azure logic apps

Tags: azure

I have a file that gets generated everyday with the format abc_20210901.txt(the ending of the file name is the date when the file was created which is dynamic and changes everyday) in my blob path /storageacct/ABCcontainer/abc_20210901.txt. I need to create a logic app that sends this file as an attachment in an email. I have created the 'send email' action in logic apps, but could not find how I can send this blob file as an attachment in the email.

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a minimum, you will need a get blob content v2 step followed by the send email step.
Your workflow will look like this.

[image]

Your can use Gmail or outlook. In my case, I signed into outlook to send the email. You will need to click on 'Add new parameters' and tick the attachments box to add the attachment field. [image].

You can then add your file in the Attachments Contents field.

Comment: Great. Kindly mark my reply as the answer if you're satisfied.